# Instantiating initial ViewController in AppDelegate gives flickery black screen before initial view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

In certain cases I want to set specific a specific `inital view`.
Basically to divide between onboarding and real use of the app. 
Currently, I'm using this code to do so:

```
- (void)checkWhereUserIsInOnboarding {

  UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

  if([authStatus isEqual:@3]){ // did get past certain point in onboarding
    UIViewController *initialViewController = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"connectNav"];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  }
  else if(currentUser.objectId == nil){ //no user; he/she is new to the app
    UIViewController *initialViewController = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginNav"];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  }
  else{//fully featured users
    UIViewController *initialViewController = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarcontroller"];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  }

}
```

Since I need to check this multiple times during the lifetime of the app, this function runs in the `ApplicationDidBecomeActive` method.

However, when I'm instantiating one of these VC's as initial view, I always get a black screen for about 100ms, after which the app goes on to the right screen.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A "black screen" seems to imply your app is being killed off in the background. If you swap out of the app then invoke the application switcher does your app show as a black screen?

As a starting point it's probably a good to run it under Instruments and watch things like memory etc. to make sure IOS isn't shutting it down.

Comment: what do you mean by 'invoke the application switcher'?

Comment: Double click the home button…